# Reading nested and non-nested from Parquet

Tags: go, parquet

I have a large Parquet (GBs) that looks like this:

> fields: 3
>
> - foo: type=utf8, nullable
> - bar: type=float64, nullable
> - nested: type=list<list:float64, nullable>

Note, the nested data column.
Now I want to read that Parquet in row slices of 1024 rows per column.

I tried:

```golang
f, _ := file.OpenParquetFile(filepath, true)
rdr, _ := pqarrow.NewFileReader(f, pqarrow.ArrowReadProperties{})
colIndices := []int{0, 1, 2}
rowGroups := []int{0, 1, 2}
crs, _, _ := rdr.GetFieldReaders(ctx, colIndices, rowGroups)
nestedCr := crs[2]
chunked, _ := nestedCr.NextBatch(1024)
for _, c := range chunked.Chunks() {
  l := arr.(*array.List)
  fl := l.ListValues().(*array.Float64)
  // here I have no idea how many of the nested ListValues belong to the current row or the next.
}
```

While reading unnested parquet columns are easy enough - matching rows of unnested and nested Columns is a mystery to me.

Would appreciate if anyone could untangle that for me :)

Comment: Actually reading data via pqarrow automatically recursively fetches nested data.